# Selecting Multiple Cassandra Rows in one Select, With Composite Primary Key

Tags: nosql, cassandra, cql

I'm trying to write a select statement using CQL3 against Cassandra that will return multiple rows.  Under normal circumstances, I could specify the partition key using an IN statement, but the wrinkle for my use case is that I'm dealing with a composite partition key.

For example:

```
create table MyTable (
  my_key_1 text,
  my_key_2 text,
  my_value text,
  primary key ((my_key_1, my_key_2))
);
```

With this table structure, I want to select the following rows by key value in a single query.

```
Row 1: my_key_1 = 'key1value1', my_key_2 = 'key2value1'
Row 2: my_key_1 = 'key1value2', my_key_2 = 'key2value2'
```

Is this possible?  For the sake of argument, I know that I could create a partition key out of my_key_1 and a cluster key of my_key_2, but "my_key_1" will be extremely dense, and better specified WITH my_key_2 as the partition key.

I've tried using a `select * from MyTable where my_key_1 in ('key1value1', 'key1value2') and my_key_2 in ('key2value1', 'key2value2')`, but I receive an error that on the the last part of the partition key can be contained in an IN list query like this.  So, is there any way to do this, or am I going to have to "materialize" the my_key_1 + my_key_2 value to the primary key and query by that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, CQL does not support this as of 2.0.5.  If you look at the [original work item](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-4179) implementing composite keys, querying over multiple combinations was specifically left out due to implementation complexities.

For now your only recourse would be to combine the keys on the client-side and treat them as one column in Cassandra (or you can break up your multiple row query into several single-row)